# user login redirect always to homepage

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-login

I am creating alogin view in which when user is not none then logged in it should go to same page before login , then also go to other url , but it always goes to the other url though it should go to first redirect

views.py

```
def login_page(request):
form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
context = {
        "form": form
        }
next_get_url= request.GET.get('next')
next_post_url= request.POST.get('next')
redirect_path = next_get_url or next_post_url or None
if form.is_valid():
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        if  is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return(redirect(redirect_path))
        else:
            return (redirect('/'))
    else:
        print ("Error")
return render(request, "accounts/login.html",context)
```

forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

i mean it always go to this case:

```
 else:
        return (redirect('/'))
```

whenever this is the case:

```
if  is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return(redirect(redirect_path))
```

all tries and solutions found did not solve this any help! and thanks in advance

Comment: i think no need of request in **authenticate** function

Comment: I removed it but still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Django comes with a [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) that handles the redirect for you. it would be better to use that than write your own view.

If you do write your own view, then you need to include your `redirect_path` in your `context` dictionary [here is where Django does is](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L97), and then you need to include it as a hidden field in the login form (see the example template [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) for `LoginView`:

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
</form>
```

Comment: so how to make next the same page i was in before logging in?

Comment: Include `next` in the template context, e.g. `context['next'] = redirect_path`. I can't help you debug your own view any more than that, since I think it would be better to use `LoginView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`redirect_path = next_get_url or next_post_url or "/"`

because if you pass `None` to `is_safe_url`, it will return `False` as it only takes valid urls.

Comment: it always goes to "/' i need the opposite

Comment: Try printing `is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host())`. It will return `False` if your request does not have `next_get_url` or `next_post_url`. That is why you need to change this line.
What does `print(user)` print?

Comment: yes you are right  so, how to make next_get_url be True?

Comment: print(user) prints username

Comment: You can add a hidden field in your form `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ value_of_the_url_where_you_want_to_redirect }}">`, or you can simply define it in the view itself, if you want to control it from backend.

Answer (score 0):

try a render methodes li this

```
def my_view(request):

username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    # Redirect to a success page.
    render(request , 'bootstrap/page_learn.html')
else:
    # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
    render(request , 'bootstrap/page_learn.html')
```

Comment: i just need it to return to same page after login not redirected to homepage